# Is this ALAssetsGroup on iCloud?

Tags: ios6, icloud

I was trying to figure out if the ALAssetsGroup I had a pointer to was hosted on/copied to iCloud.  Not finding the question already asked, I was able to figure it out.

Use valueForProperty on the group object with ALAssetsGroupPropertyType.  This returns an NSNumber which is a bitmask of several flags include ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL) isICloudAlbum:(ALAssetsGroup*)group {
    NSNumber *groupType = [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyType];

    return ([groupType intValue] & ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream) ? YES : NO;
}
```